# Eslint with node.js - Parsing error: Assigning to rvalue

Tags: node.js, eslint

I'm trying to use a JS linter for the first time and have chosen eslint to test some AWS Lambda functions written in NodeJS. I get an immediate error that has me stumped.

```
module.exports.replyGet = ( event, context, callback ) => {
```

Generates the following error

```
14:28  error  Parsing error: Assigning to rvalue
```

My .eslintrc.js reads as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  "rules": {
    "no-console":0
  },
  "extends": "eslint:recommended"
};
```

Can anybody advise a novice on how best to fix the error?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your eslint config file

```
"env": {
    "es6": true,
    "node": true
 }
```